# PYTHON Nuitka ошибка компиляции

Tags: python, компиляция, nuitka

Немного предыстории.
Я создаю маленький проект и хочу чтобы он был скомпилирован в exe.
И я решил использовать для компиляции nuitka-у, но при попытке компиляции выдает такую ошибку:

```
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Nuitka\Nuitka\gcc\x86_64\10.2.0-11.0.0-8.0.0-r5\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe (gcc.exe).
static_src\MainProgram.c: In function 'main':
static_src\MainProgram.c:443:42: error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
  443 |     Py_SetPythonHome(L"" PYTHON_HOME_PATH);
      |                                          ^
```

Для компиляции использую команду:

```
python -m nuitka --follow-imports main.py
```

Подскажите как исправить данную ошибку?

(Проблема решена ошибка возникала из за того что в пути содержались символы из кириллицы)

Comment: Может проблема в коме на 443 строке?

Comment: Мне кажется есть смысл [issue на гитхабе создать](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues)

Comment: "(Проблема решена ошибка возникала из за того что в пути содержались символы из кириллицы)" - а как решили в итоге?

Comment: @insolor переместил проект.